# Visual C++ 2017 - Decrease Error Level

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

I have moved from VS2010 to VS2017.

The code is compilable in VS2010 but throws one error in VS2017 - **C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable**. It does initialized.

The dirty workaround I am using right now is:

```
#pragma warning (disable:4703)
```

And everything works fine.

My question is how to decrease the level of "pedantry" or how to solve this issue in a safety way?

Comment: How about initializing variable? This warning happens for a reason.

Comment: Erm, you did disable it.  It is not an error, merely a level 4 warning. Compiling with /W4 in effect is not easy and you are almost always forced to disable a bunch of chatter.  Presumably a previous maintainer of the code already did this.  They do add new diagnostics in new compiler releases so whatever he did is likely to be not sufficient.  /W3 is a sane selection.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of making your dirty hack work, you should post your *actual problem*.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not recommended to decrease warning level.**

But if you need to do so, it can be done by:

1. Go to `project properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Warning Level`
2. Set it to a lower value

Comment: If it is not recommended I will be happy to solve it in the correct way. But the variable is initialized. Other suggestions?

Comment: @lar.soo It is usually caused by your variable will only be initialized under specific conditions. i.e. You have an variable initialized inside an `if` statement, it will only be initialized when `if` is true. You can show your code which causes this warning so we can be sure why it happens.